# How will get the count using RestAPI with filter query

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online

I will not get all the item on one time so i can't use `.length` of.

So I tried this rest API to get over all count.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('FAQ')/itemcount
```

It is working fine but with this api I can't pass any filter condition like `isdisplay eq 1`, so I moved to webservice "_vti_bin" call of

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/FAQ/$count?$filter=IsDisplay eq true
```

But it is showing "Request Error" page in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One solution could be to return the count in a custom response header in the service returning the list of items.

Comment: are you meantion this header? headers: { "Accept": "text/plain;odata=verbose" } - using this also i couldn't able to get count

Comment: No, on server-side you could add a custom header (choose the name you want) and add it to your response headers.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't understand your answer. i tried to get count of items in sharepoint online list using Rest API. where i have to add the headers. can you please give me the full detail for this.

Answer (score 1):

My test result:

[image]

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyList/$count?$filter=IsDisplay%20eq%20true
```

[image]

Or you could get `data.d.results.length` by rest api with filter

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=Title,Id&$filter=IsDisplay%20eq%201
```

Comment: Using "data.d.results.length" we can get the count but using itemCount it self we can't pass any filter -------here----> "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/itemCount".